# API requires a user-agent to be set but its a unsafe header in chrome

Tags: vue.js, axios, user-agent

I've been trying to request information from the Shoppy API, and the response I'm getting on chrome and opera is this

[image: this]

In the Shoppy API documentation it says that it's required to set a user-agent which is impossible to my understanding from looking at stack overflow posts. However, the question I am wondering about is if there is a workaround?

sidenote: with firefox i successfully get a response from the API with a CORS extension enabled.

[shoppy api documentation](https://shoppy.dev/#/)

```
mounted () {
 axios
  .get('https://shoppy.gg/api/v1/products/', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'placeholder',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://shoppy.gg',
      useCredentails: true, 'user-agent': 'Shoppy'}})
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  // .then(response => (this.info = response))

}
```

Comment: Your browser automatically sets the `User-agent` request header. Also, `useCredentials` should not be in your `headers` object and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not a **request** header, it can only come from the server in a **response**

Comment: As for your CORS issues, there's hundreds of duplicates on StackOverflow. I'll try and find a nice one.

Comment: Thank you Phil my CORS and user-agent problem is no more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to worry about setting a user-agent if you're using their API from a non-browser client app. If you're using their API on a Web site via a browser, then the browser's user-agent will automatically be used, without you having to do anything.

Comment: This worked thank you Joseph